# How to use Soundcloud javascript sdk in angular2 module

Tags: javascript, angular, soundcloud, ionic2

I have been trying to use the soundcloud javascript sdk [soundcloud javascript sdk](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks)  in my ionic 2 app. but i don't know how to make the SC object visible within my service module.
I have included the sdk in my index.html like so 
I am trying to make sure the SC object is avilable withing th module but i get a ts error saying cannot find mobule SC.

```js
export class SCService {
  constructor() {
   console.log(SC);
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-app></ion-app>
  <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <!-- Polyfill needed for platforms without Promise and Collection support -->
  <script src="build/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Zone.js and Reflect-metadata  -->
  <script src="build/js/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="build/js/zone.js"></script>
  <!-- the bundle which is built from the app's source code -->
  <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable `SC` outside your class and then use it inside your component

```
declare var SC: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like this `window['SC'].Widget.Events` similar to `SC.Widget.Events` as normal.